# Can AddressSanitizer (or any other tool) detect memory bugs in Android native code binaries without needing compilation?

Tags: android, native-code, address-sanitizer, frida

Google's `AddressSanitizer` detects memory bugs in Android native code.  [It does require](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/asan), however, that the target binary (i.e., executable or library) be recompiled with whatever flags and settings it needs:

> AddressSanitizer (ASan) is a fast compiler-based tool for detecting memory bugs in native code.

Is there a tool that can detect Android memory bugs *without* requiring any recompilation of the target binary?  Here are some thoughts of what such a tool would look like:

- The tool should intercept/hook the relevant memory-related functions in `libc.so` (e.g., malloc, free, calloc, realloc), similar to [Frida](https://frida.re/)'s ability to intercept any native code function.
- The tool should work by its being injected into a process space.  From that point, everything should "just work".
- It should also intercept both hardware faults and software exceptions (e.g., segmentation faults) to detect a memory bug.
- It would be reasonable to assume this tool would not be as powerful as compiler-based AddressSanitizer, but that's to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/frida/frida-gum

Helper libraries for developers needing highly granular:

Heap allocation tracking and leak checking.

https://github.com/frida/frida-gum/tree/master/libs/gum/heap

Profiling with worst-case inspector callback.

https://github.com/frida/frida-gum/blob/7e4c5b547b035ae05d2f9e160652101bf741e6c3/libs/gum/prof/gumprofiler.h#L40-L42
https://github.com/frida/frida-gum/tree/master/libs/gum/prof

Comment: I use frida-trace quite often, and am aware of the underlying Gum framework, but you have given me a push to investigate Gum up close -- thanks!